# Session handling in backend program

Tags: java, jsp, session, backend

I've have written a little game in Java and using a Webpage as frontend (using Tomcat 8 integrated in Eclipse). The session handling on the front end is no problem. However I got none on the backend.

```
<%  //Prepare Game
    request.getSession();
    Controller master = (Controller) session.getAttribute("master");
    if (master == null){
        master = new Controller();
        master.prepareGame();   
    }
    session.setAttribute("master", master);
%>
```

The Controller will overwrite existing objects when another user uses the application. Which means that they both do have differend sessions but the same controller object, which is a problem :D
I have no clue how to manage the session on the backend. If you got any advise for a newbie  that would be great :)

Comment: Your code looks correct. My guess is that there is a configuration issue. Are you using a proxy in front of tomcat?

Comment: Oh! are You trying to connect with different users from the same machine?

Comment: You say that two users "have different sessions but the same controller object".   Did you check that by printing the sessionId on the page? Did you try using two different browsers(one for each user) at the same time?  Also, since a JSP automatically joins a session, you should remove the line request.getSession();

Comment: I tried connecting from differend machines. Session is not the same, however I'm pretty sure the backend program is not able to manage more than one user, since it seems it always works on the same (Controller class) object.